# Questions about transformation or integral transformation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I have asked several mathematicians about the following questions,but all of them think they are good questions,but can not give a complete answer.Now I have to come here to ask mathematicians all over the world,and hope that I can get a complete answer or some constructive suggestions.

Given $$\frac{P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}{P_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}\text{, and  }\frac{P_3(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}{P_4(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}$$ where $P_i$ is polynomial(that is $P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n), P_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n), P_3(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n), P_4(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$ are polynomial) whose coefficients are over $\mathbb{Q}$,let $J$ be  Jacobian matrix, when does $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ exist,such that $$\frac{P_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}{P_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)}=\frac{P_3(f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))}{P_4(f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))}|\det (J(f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)))|\text{ ,}$$  and $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$  is bijective ?

When $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is restricted to differential polynomials, rational functions, algebraic functions,or just all differential function including  transcendental functions over $\mathbb{C}$ , $\mathbb{R}$, what is the condition or non-condition for the existence of $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ ?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180876/when-is-there-a-polynomial-transformation

Comment: @NoahS,yes,it is related,but some people think it is not clearly expressed,so it has been closed.Now I rephrase them and having asked mathematicians around me without any complete answer and constructive suggestion,I have to post it here.

Comment: Your question is far too general for there to be any hope of a comprehensive solution.  This is why you aren't getting any answers.  I suggest that you try to solve the case $n=1$, i.e., give necessary and sufficient conditions for a bijective solution in that case for general polynomials in one variable.  If you are able to find computable and interesting criteria in this case, try $n=2$.  If you can't do that, then asking the question for general $n$ is probably not worthwhile.  By the way, it seems highly unlikely to me that such an approach will shed any light on the Jacobian Conjecture.

Comment: @RobertBryant,thank you for your comment.Yes,extending the simple case to complex one and one variable to $n$ variable is an approach.Since I am not a mathematician,I guess maybe someone can give a general complete answer.But to tell the truth,those question is not motivated by Jacobian Conjecture,nor do I have any intention to solve Jacobian Conjecture(in fact I am not so ambitious to try the Jacobian Conjecture),although it maybe is related to the Conjecture

Comment: @XL_at_China:  For example, consider the question of whether there is a bijective solution $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to the equation $$\frac1{x^2+1} = \frac{a_k}{f(x)^{2k}+1}f'(x)$$ when $k>1$ is an integer for some constant $a_k$ and how you would determine that constant $a_k$.  That's only one sample of the kind of thing you'd have to be able to answer, even in the case $n=1$.

Comment: @RobertBryant,thank you very much,your comments are very helpful

Comment: @RobertBryant a famous mathematician has told me that it is Jacobian Conjecture ,but I think those questions are much weaker than Jacobian Conjecture

Comment: @XL_at_China:  I agree that it is not literally the Jacobian Conjecture, but it does seem that, in order to answer your question, you will have to have a constructive method for finding a candidate mapping $f$ and deciding whether or not it is polynomial.  If you could do that, it seems highly likely to me that you would have to be able to solve the Jacobian conjecture along the way, so I think it's actually stronger. For example, in the case, $n=1$, the Jacobian Conjecture is trivial, but your problem is definitely not.

Comment: @RobertBryant,yes,if so, it is very strong and tough questions.

Comment: Okay, let me post the wiki of Jacobian Conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture